# How would my circuit vary if my DS18B20 comes on a 'Keyes' module?

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, esp32

I am looking at the following tutorial on how to link the DS18B20 to an esp32 module: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-ds18b20-temperature-arduino-ide/

For the parasite mode, I have the following diagram:
[image]

I have a Keyes DS18B20 module instead: https://www.tautvidas.com/blog/2015/09/measuring-temperature-with-ds18b20-temperature-sensor/

I was wondering how that would change my circuit? Would I just replace the resistor on the diagram with a wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawing you have had the following pin order for the sensor IC.
[image]

The **module** which you are planning to use has different pin order.
From the left:
GND VCC SIGNAL.

[image].

You have to connect first two pins of the temperature sensor from the left to the ground (last but one row). Connect GPIO to the third pin.

Forgivr my bad drawing.. the red colour indicates no connection.. remove the resistor. You don't need it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. Would VDD be the same as VCC and SIGNAL be the same as DQ as it seems to be from your cirucit? I can see that just the rightmost two pins switch?

Comment: Yes.. VDD is same as VCC...... And Signal is same as DQ